# Android options for extremely wide canvas

Tags: android

I've been attempting to get an extremely large canvas working for several days now.

After adding everything to the canvas, the width of the canvas is sometimes 30,000 but if add this code to the ondraw method, scrolling horiztonally becomes really slow.

I then tried to add everything to a bitmap and then draw the bitmap in the onDraw method. Whilst this worked fine for smaller bitmaps, I'm getting out of memory error for the bitmap that is 30,000 wide.

Can anyone suggest a solution please and I'n not sure what to try now.

Thanks

edit I've also tried changing the bitmap to Config.RGB_565 but I still get the memory errors.

Comment: Can you stick to drawing the visible part? Are you not drawing the whole canvas or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm drawing the whole canvas at the moment since I don't really know how to only draw the visible part.

Comment: can you use a ViewPort with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many entries do you have in your ArrayList, it appears to be quite large.

From my understanding, you don't have OoM issue with drawing everything in onDraw(), but that it's really slow? If that's the case, the most like reason is that you are calling a large numbers of *drawText*, this is *very* slow, basically if you had 10000 Strings to draw, the system will have to measure each and every one of them in order to just determine whether the given String would be visible on your large canvas, and then the actual drawing part is slow as well.

You can test the amount of time taken for drawing all the text and see if this is the case.

If it is indeed the case, then the easiest way is to map each character/number to a bitmap, you can have an artist create the PNG files, or draw each unique character you would need in your *onCreate(Bundle)* or some other called-once-per-Activity-creation method, put the bitmaps in a String-to-Bitmap HashMap, and instead of calling

```
canvas.drawText(bellNumber, xPad, mOriginY, paint);
```

you call something like

```
canvas.drawBitmap(hash.get(bellNumber), src, dst, paint); //remember to reuse src & dst
```

This will bypass String related drawing overhead completely and should make your onDraw operation quite a bit faster.

Comment: Yes, doing everything in the onDraw does not give me OutofMemory error's. The biggest ArrayList contains upto 1500 items.

Creating a bitmap and doing all the drawing once would have been the best solution, but as you said maybe I should try and limit the number of drawText calls to only the visible proportion of the screen. Thanks.

Comment: I don't thing I'm going to create the PNG files as there are thousands of different bells.

Comment: I suggest you first make sure that drawText is indeed the problem. If so and there are too many different Strings, another way is to just measure the String width once and caches it, and just check against the cached String width/height to determine if it is visible.

Comment: Thank you very much Kai. Initially I was calling draw text for each character, but now I reduced the number of onDraw calls to each row and it's working really fast now.

I've spent so much time on this, I wish I had tried it earlier. I did n't even need to create a HashMap as it's improve the scrolling substantially.

Comment: Also just to add, now I don't need to perform any calculations to draw  what is visible on the screen. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Dealing with a large Canvas will continually run into OutOfMemoryExceptions. A Canvas writes to a Bitmap, and something like a 30,000 by X Bitmap will take up a lot of memory.  I think your best alternative is to keep track of the visible screen's position relative to what you want to display, and only write to the canvas what is needed.

For example if the user scrolls 100 pixels down and to the left, then for a 1024 x 768 display, draw to the canvas what would be displayed at 1124 and 868 in your virtual 30,000 x 30,000 canvas (which you don't draw in whole).

Comment: Thanks, have you seen any examples where this is done? All the tutorials I have seen just draw to one bitmap.

In my drawing method I'm looping through an ArrayList, so I'm not sure how to only draw certain elements from the list depending on the current position.

I'm also using a HoriztonalScrollView to handle the scrolling.

Comment: Also if I do the all the drawing in the onDraw method, I able to display everything although the scrolling is very slow.

Is this method not also creating a bitmap just as large as if I were to do it manually?

How is this being achieved?

Comment: What sort of image(s) are you trying to draw?  It might better help me provide you an example if I knew more about what you were trying to draw.

Comment: I'm trying loop through an ArrayList and drawing each list's values on the screen. Then I also draw a series of lines on the text. Here's the code for what I'm trying to do:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12945652/RowView.java

As I said before, if I put all the drawing code in the onDraw method, it is able to create and display the entire view, however scrolling is very laggy.

Comment: And this is what the output should look like.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12945652/temp.PNG

Comment: Sorry, looks like your code was kind of what I was thinking, I don't have any further suggestions :(

Answer (score 1):

Bitmaps have a limited size depending on the device - but it is usually dependent on the size of the particular device. Also, bitmaps are one of the primary ways of creating a memory leak for sdk-based apps. Your best bet will be to split your canvas up into smaller sections, or consider other options, such as rendering a canvas in openGL (this also has size limitations, but will generally render faster).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried splitting the canvas into many smaller bitmap and then draw that bitmap.
Afterwards I try to free the bitmap but it's causing a memory leak since the previous bitmap is not being destroyed.
Also using the recycle() method clears the memory but it keeps repeating the same bitmap over and over again.

Comment: This is the attempt with splitting up into multiple bitmaps:
http://pastebin.com/CXm0eiDJ

But as I said before setting the bitmap = null, does not free the bitmap.

Comment: Not sure how your project is setup, but Recycle() doesn't work when the image view is hardware accelerated.

Answer (score 0):

Flynn81 has a good answer overall. Looking at your row logic, I would do some math and try to predict which rows need to be drawn. Since you are dealing with text, you can get the font metrics (measuring the text). Since it seems like you are dealing with numbers, you can try to measure the height of a string like "0123456789".

You may want to profile this, but you might be able to cache the line drawing.

If you are really brave, you could try using a ListView and custom drawable types